# DialogFlow Slot Filling

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm playing around with DialogFlow and trying to make a simple bot that allows you to make a list.

I've got a single entity called list and a reference value called name. I've created an intent called make_list with an action called make_list. I have a few templated training phrases that look like this:

```
create a list called @list:name
add a list called list:name
```

Unfortunately, when i test this out it doesn't seem to do what i expect (it doesn't fill the name parameter). If I mark the parameter as required I get stuck in a loop where it just keeps asking me.

Oddly, if i add a bunch of reference values to my list entity (pizza, shopping list, etc) and i test my bot with the phrase "add a list called pizza" it fills the name parameter with pizza.

I'm sure I've missed something. I've watched various youtube videos and demos and it seems like what I'm doing should work. Please help!

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 1):

> Oddly, if i add a bunch of reference values to my list entity (pizza,
>   shopping list, etc) and i test my bot with the phrase "add a list
>   called pizza" it fills the name parameter with pizza.

It's not odd, that's how it is supposed to work. Dialogflow does not know what `@list` is unless you add values to that entity.

For your particular case you can use the system entity: `@sys.any` which will match any non-empty input.

```
create a list called @sys.any:name
add list called @sys.any:name
```